# Why is my debugger so slow?

Tags: delphi, debugging

Since some time, my Delphi debugger became much slower than I was used to before.

I noticed this in both Delphi 2007 and 2009, so it seems it's something outside of Delphi itself...

What causes this behaviour, and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After weeks of searching for an answer, I found this Microsoft knowledge base article fixes my problem : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321410/nl

The point is, I installed Microsoft Script Editor a while back to do some server-side javascript debugging. This also installs a service called "Machine Debug Manager" (Mdm.exe), which is the cause for the slowdown. After disabling this service, debugger speed returned to normal!

Answer (score 3):

For non-dutch speakers

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321410

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, it started after I installed XP Service pack 3 and stopped after we switched from a Windows Workgroup to a Domain.

While I was lingering in slowness I found that if I started my program, them attached to the process I could debug at normal speeds.

I also read that sometimes the Data Execution Prevention settings can adversely affect debugging performance, although monkeying with that never helped my cause.